# "deny from all" with a custom message?

Tags: .htaccess

I'm moving to a new server and want to take all of my sites offline during the transition. I know I can put this in my root .htaccess file to block people from visiting the site:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
```

But I want to also output a message explaining why the site is down. Is this possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try adding a:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /special_message.html
```

where the `/special_message.html` is the file that contains your message.

Comment: This is a good start, but doesn't work with sub-URLs, if you're getting message similar to `Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.` See this answer of mine for solution - https://stackoverflow.com/a/66322976/1835470

Answer (score 5):

you can add a message directly from .htaccess file, eg:

`ErrorDocument 403 "Account Suspended"`

I think last quote is optional too.

Comment: Yes, the quotes are optional.