# htaccess 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-403, custom-pages

I want to have a custom 403 page in my project. So I added these codes in a .htaccess file:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 192.168.1.0/24

ErrorDocument 403 /403.htm
```

But when the project runs from an out of rang IP, and 403 error must be occurred, custom 403 page redirect does not work and I give another error too.

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /app/ on this server.
>   **Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.**

What is this problem for? I have read different articles inside StackOverflow and other websites, but none of them could not solve this problem.

Comment: The rule you provided `ErrorDocument 403 /403.htm` are you sure the page is definitely present there `/403.htm` you might have to provide full path to your error page.

Comment: 403.htm is available in the root of project.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the `deny from all` denies **everything** including the error documents.

But hey, .htaccess files work in cascade, so you can

1. create a subfolder in your web root (assuming your webroot is `/www` - `/www/errordocs`
2. => in there put your ErrorDocuments like 403.html etc.
3. create another `.htaccess` **there** - `/www/errordocs/.htaccess`
4. => into this `/www/errordocs/.htaccess` put `allow from all`
5. In the main `.htaccess` in the webroot (`/www/.htaccess` 
   ) put
   `ErrorDocument 403 /errordocs/403.html` etc..

If this is still not working for you, check there are public/others/everyone READ permissions on both the folder and the file

`/www/errordocs`           => `755`

`/www/errordocs/.htaccess` => `640`

`/www/errordocs/403.html`  => `644`

Don't be confused - Windows OS **also** has permissions, you will need at least Read permissions for `Everyone` on these, [more on the Windows permissions here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-2000-server/bb727008(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

**Just remember, files in this folder will all be public!** (don't put there anything you don't want public :-)

Answer (score -4):

yes I can help a Little bit to solve permission issue , I was encountered by same problem , You just need to give permission +777 to your /app

if you have linux machine , go inside your web folder

```
sudo chmod -R +777 /app
```

and do the same to any other folders you write there

and for 403 error I think you missed "l" If I am not wrong ,

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 192.168.1.0/24

ErrorDocument 403 /403.html
```

:) :)

Comment: I am running this project on Windows. So there is no such permission issue on it.

Comment: @MohammadSaberi usually on server when we deploy project , there are some permission issues on web folder , on windows it must be read only ... that why it is throwing error , as .htaccess file rewrites this folder

Comment: **In 99% cases setting 777 / allow everybody everything permissions is not the correct solution**, max permissions you should ever set are **`775`**, ideally no more than `755` but there are a few hosts where you need `775`